# Why only one thread is running in multithread program- python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to python , I using threading module open 25 thread for a process in python:

```
import queue
import threading

def extraInfo(task,ResList):
    '''
    Do something here 
    '''
def multiExtraInfo(q, thread_no, ResList):
    while True:
        task = q.get()
        extraInfo(task, ResList)
        q.task_done()
        print(f'Thread #{thread_no} is doing task #{task} in the queue.') 

q = queue.Queue()
ResList = []
for i in range(25):
    worker = threading.Thread(target = multiExtraInfo, args = (q,i, ResList), daemon = True)
    worker.start()

JobList = list(range(1,40))
for i in JobList:
    q.put(i)
q.join()
print(" multithread job finished! ")
```

but when I using top to check if my program is runnig correctly, I found there is noly one thread which state is running , others are waitting for resource. The output of top command " top -H -u kong*** " is like the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCJ1a.png)

If my code about mutlithread is correct ? And why there is only one thread running, and others waitting for resource? The HPC administrator tell me that there is no calculation resource limit for users.

Comment: What is `JobList`? This code won't run as provided.

Comment: Python only lets a single thread run at a time because its memory management and reference counting system is not thread safe. The Global Interpreter Lock can only be held by a single python thread at a time.

Comment: @tdelaney thank you for your answer, but why this frame of multithread works when i test it using time.sleep(): the function of each thread is start and sleepping for few seconds and thread function done.

Comment: @Grismar thank you for your reply, i changed my question. the JobList is just a list of job id which i used to start the thread.

Comment: @xinking tdelaney answered your question. Python can only run one thread at a time due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). Python switches between threads when the running thread sleeps, blocks or after running a certain number of operations. I can't remember the number. But only one thread is ever running at any given time. If you want true multiprocessing then look at pythons multiprocessing module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Your threads are all running, and taking on the work, but they are threads and no processes, and so only one will actually run at a time, as others have indicated.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide thanks for your help, I get your point, only one thread is alive but interpreter will switch between different opened thread. By the why, if i using os.system() to using other Linux program within each thread, if the linux program will runing continuously under this kind of switch of interpreter(sorry for this naive and sudden question)

Comment: What command are you running in `os.system`?

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide I call some bioinformatic program which may written in c++, i using ```os.system``` to call it in thread and pass different argument for different thread, i don't know what is the true running state of these program with only one thread is truly alive in python.

Comment: It's the *python interpreter* that can only be executing in a single thread.  When a Python thread calls `os.system()`, that thread will *block* waiting for the child process to exit, and while that Python thread is blocked, another Python thread can use the interpreter (and call `os.system()` if it wants to)

Comment: @xinking so I ask what command your running for two reasons. 1. Is this a spawn command or a execute command. 2. Are you wanting/using what is returned by this command? Based on your comment it seems like this is a execute command. Are you retrieving a response and processing that or something else? Either way multiprocessing will be able to do what you want or using the `subprocess` module with a non blocking call like `Popen` might work for what you need.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks for your answer, while the thread is block, if the child process is keep running? if that means all the child process of each process will running at the same time like multi-process ? if my understanding is correct? (sorry for bother again)

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide thanks for your patient reply, i will try multi-process!

Comment: @xinking yes, all processes in a modern OS run independently of each other, so if your python process has multiple threads, and each thread has spawned a child process, the child process can all run simultaneously.  In particular, the child processes are not governed by the parent process's Global Interpreter Lock because the GIL only applies to the python threads inside the parent process, not to other processes in the system.